# How to display accurate timestamp on apexcharts using angular8?

Tags: angular, apexcharts

Timestamp data(start time and end time) are not matching with apex chart time series.

I am trying to display exact time-interval from the timestamp on the apex chart using angular, but I am not receiving expected results which are shown in [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/122E7.png).

Here is my apex chart configuration:

```
  series: chartSeriesData,
        chart: {
            height: 200,
            width: '100%',
            type: 'bar',
            events: {
                dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => {
                        const xaxis = {min : config.w.config.series[config.seriesIndex].data[config.dataPointIndex][0], max: ''};
                        this.selectedRowsEvent(xaxis, 'click');
                },
                zoomed: (chartContext, { xaxis, yaxis }) => {
                    this.selectedRowsEvent(xaxis,null);
                },
                scrolled: function(chartContext, { xaxis }) {
                }
            },
            // zoom: {
            //     enabled: true,
            //     type: 'x',
            //     autoScaleYaxis: false
            // },
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend : {
            itemMargin: {
                horizontal: 10,
                vertical: 20
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min : this.sortedChartData[0].timestamp,
            max : this.sortedChartData[this.sortedChartData.length - 1].timestamp,
            axisTicks: {
                show: true,
                borderType: 'solid',
                color: '#78909C',
                height: 6,
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            show : false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function (value, opts) {
                    return '';
                },
            },
        },
        tooltip : {
            // shared: true,
            y: {
                formatter : undefined,
                title: {
                    formatter: (seriesName) =>  seriesName ,
                },
            },
        },
        
        colors: [ '#78ad68', '#EF6301', '#EB2300', '#56b4d1', '#fad652']
    };
    
}
```

Comment: why not using `rangebar` ? see this: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/zYqNZRo also here is the official docs for timeline charts: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but we need a toolbar to perform a few operations. so, we chose bar charts.